AWS Cognito ListUsersAsync call fails to find user by phone number
I've come across the strangest issue with AWS Cognito. If my UI creates a non SSO user with a valid phone number, my API (which uses the .NET AWS SDK to call the AmazonCognitoIdentityProviderClient.ListUserAsync endpoint) finds the user by their phone number successfully. However, if I create an SSO user through Google login, the API fails to find the user by phone number.
But, the weird thing is if I edit the user in the Cognito console and add a random extra digit to the phone number and save it, the API finds the user with the edited number just fine. But, if I edit the user again and remove the random digit (returning the number to the one originally used during signup), the API fails to find the user again.
What am I missing here? Is this some weird indexing thing with SSO based users in Cognito?
